# How to fix missing object/variable in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know this similar question has been posted before but I just couldn't figure it out for my case. People also suggest to install the github version of ggplot2 which I've tried and still get same error. Below is my code:

```
ageDF = data.frame(cbind(dataset$survival_time, dataset$age))
ageDF = ageDF[complete.cases(ageDF), ]
ggplot(ageDF, aes(x = age, y = survival_time))
+ geom_point(col = "blue") + geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

I know my code is working up until the point I call `ggplot()`. My use case seems really simple too. But I get this error:

```
11.FUN(X[[i]], ...)
10.lapply(aesthetics[new_aesthetics], eval_tidy, data = data)
9.scales_add_defaults(plot$scales, data, aesthetics, plot$plot_env)
8.f(..., self = self)
7.l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
6.f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
5.by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
4.ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
3.ggplot_build(x)
2.print.ggplot(x)
1.(function (x, ...) UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

Comment: including a small sample of your dataset / reprex would really help in understanding what's going

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ageDF = data.frame(cbind(dataset$survival_time, dataset$age))` line changes your variable names and they are no longer called `survival_time` and `age`.

See this for example with `mtcars` dataset -

```
agedf <- data.frame(cbind(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$am))
head(agedf)

#    X1 X2
#1 21.0  1
#2 21.0  1
#3 22.8  1
#4 21.4  0
#5 18.7  0
#6 18.1  0
```

To keep the same variable names in the subsetted dataframe you can do -

```
agedf <- data.frame(mpg = mtcars$mpg, am = mtcars$am)
```

Or

```
agedf <- mtcars[c('mpg', 'am')]
```

On another note, you don't even need to subset the specific columns since in `ggplot` you can pass dataframe with additional columns but use only the ones that you require.